# Facing one error While creating Lead from the guest user

Tags: leads, guest-user

all I have one functionality where Lead is created from Guest user,

**Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER: We can't save this record because the “Training Participant Request After Flow” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: leadconvertchtr.leadConvertChatter: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: line 26, column 25: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class leadconvertchtr.LeadConvertChatter : Field is not writeable: FeedItem.CreatedById.**

I have no idea from where it is coming

Also if I create a record from an authenticated user and then try to create one with the guest user then it works fine but after some time period, it again throws me this error.

I did recompile all the classes and triggers but it still throws me the same error.

If anyone has any idea Kindly let me know.

Comment: Could you please share your "leadconvertchtr" class source code? It seems that you are trying to assign value to CreatedById field. Unfortunately you cannot assign custom value to CreatedById field. It is populated automatically.

Comment: Looks like this error happens in Installed Package with namespace `leadconvertchtr`. You cannot see code source from managed packages, but you can log a case with their support so they can refactored their code.

Comment: Exactly @ArnasBaronas I have no access to this class. What MariiaIllarionova mentioned I believe that's the way but if anyone else knows the way to resolve it other than contacting support. Do let me know.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, but still no solution.

Comment: This is not possible to be resolved on your side, unfortunately. Temporary solution could be to uninstall this package and install in after fixes from their side, so not errors occur during your save/update procedure.